# How much should I charge for my Logo design work?

Tags: freelance

I just designed a logo for a new company starting out in London. Four young people who recently graduated from university. Unfortunately I didnt set a price with them before i designed the logo. Very stupid of me...but it was my first freelance job. 
I am asking for £200 for 5 hours of work. They now came back that they dont have the money and the max. they will pay is £100 or they wont use the Logo.

I recently graduated as welll...so I dont know a lot about freelance prices. Should I except this? Is that a fair price? I have no idea....

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you were a plumber, client asks you to fix the toilet and you send them a bill and they refuse to pay? Well no problem you will just send the bill to debt collection. In case of companies you just post a outstanding depth on them and they will have a really hard time getting anything done as they now have to work cash up front on everything.

Is 200£ unreasonable? No i dont think so (in fact it is dirt low). Is it reasonable for you to accept a 50% rebate. Depends you certainly can negotiate this. But personally i would just walk away with a 200£ life lesson learned as fighting over this is not worth it.

Always ask for part of the money up front before you begin. This has two functions:

1. You get something for your work regardless.
2. You raise the question of how you are supposed to get paid in a natural way. The client will have to budget your expenses at the point money is on the table. It also make your client show his true colors.

Believe me money changes everything. Many small companies are perfectly fine until you need to extract the payment.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.
I am a recent graduate and was never told how to deal with freelance work. I now live outside the UK. 
The client I am working for are a group of students studying in London who are starting up this business. What I didnt realise when I took on the job...was that they are student!  
When I got back to them that I want £250 they said thats far too much and they dont have the money to pay that. They said the maximum they are going to pay is £100 or else they wont use the Logo. 

From now on ill set a price before I do any work for the client.